# Using flows in webfragments

Tags: cdi, jsf-2.2, flow-scope

I'm trying to build a webapp that includes a webfragment which contains a flow.

I started building a standalone version of the webapp I want to use as a webfragment. That's working. After that I converted it to this structure:

```
flow-webfragment\src\main\java\javaclasses..

flow-webfragment\src\main\resources\META-INF\beans.xml
flow-webfragment\src\main\resources\META-INF\faces-config.xml
flow-webfragment\src\main\resources\META-INF\web-fragment.xml

flow-webfragment\src\main\resources\META-INF\resources\META-INF\context.xml
flow-webfragment\src\main\resources\META-INF\resources\META-INF\myflowdir
flow-webfragment\src\main\resources\META-INF\resources\META-INF\webfragment-start.xhtml
```

I'm not sure about the structure.. If there is a better one or a convention please tell me.

The webfragment is set up correctly and my webapp recognizes it. I can go to the "webfragment-start.xhtml" page, but when I try to enter my flow, I get a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowCDIContext.flowEntered(FlowCDIContext.java:332)
at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowHandlerImpl.pushFlow(FlowHandlerImpl.java:385)
at com.sun.faces.flow.FlowHandlerImpl.transition(FlowHandlerImpl.java:280)
at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:239)
at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:182)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:132)
```

I think CDI is not correctly available, because on another project, where I'm also using JSF 2.2 and Omnifaces, I get this message

```
org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer checkCDIAvailable
```

see http://omnifaces.org/cdi/

I also followed BalusC's instruction on [how to install CDI in tomcat](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html) and it works as standalone webapp, but not as a webfragment.

I didn't find good and understandable tutorials on how to build webfragment. If you know one, you're welcome to tell me.

Every help is highly appreciated!

Kind regards,
Mischa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forgot to add

```
<Context>
<Resource name="BeanManager" 
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
    factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

to the context.xml.